# In Android Studio, what does pressing D do in the Design Preview?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, if you click on the Design Preview window while editing an XML, you can press the <kbd>D</kbd> key, and it starts jumping to different devices. I can't find anywhere that defines what it is actually doing, and when I looked at the keycap, it doesn't show anything mapped to <kbd>D</kbd>. When it first happened, it got stuck on Pixel C and choosing something else in the dropdown wouldn't work. I finally started pressing <kbd>D</kbd> again until I got back to a phone like device.

Does anyone know what the heck it is doing?

(This stems from me accidentally starting to type the word `decrement`, but the design box was active. It seems I have also stuck the preview window in API 28, and I can't change it either (the dropdown only shows 26 and 28, even though my app is targeted at 16).

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 with Keymap set to Mac OS X (10.5+) and macOS 10.14.2 (Mojave).

Comment: ok so i tried this use case and seems a bug in AS..  i restarted AS and tried to change devices with dropdown and they are working but as soon as i change devices using D button drop down stopped working

Comment: I’m so glad it isn’t just me! I’ll have to look into how to report that to Google. Were you on a Mac as well, or Windows?

Comment: :D .. i m on Windows

Answer (score 1):

When you move your cursor to the menu of choosing devices, you can see this hotkey.

Besides, the previous two icons have their own hotkey, too.

- <kbd>B</kbd> is for `Design Surface`, which is choosing for "Design" or "Blueprint", or both of them. There is an <kbd>R</kbd> for "Force Refresh Layout"
- <kbd>O</kbd> is for `Orientation`.
- <kbd>D</kbd> is for `Devices for Preview`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It only shows devices for preview

Comment: please read the question again and edit your answer. Your answer doesn't match with what is asked!